# Range of characters+numbers

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Can anyone tell how to create a range/sequence of mix of character+numbers in R. I want to create a range from SEQ1 to SEQ26000. However, the max limit of range is stored in a vector and I want to use that vector as range limit instead of a specified number.

my code:

```
snptags<-paste("SNP1":"SNP",probesnum)
```

I get these errors:

```
error in "SNP1":"SNP" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In paste("SNP1":"SNP", probesnum) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In paste("SNP1":"SNP", probesnum) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
probesnum <- 26000
snptags <- paste0("SNP",1:probesnum)
```

or

```
snptags <- sprintf("SNP%d",1:probesnum)
```

Comment: You may want to consider using `seq_len(probesnum)` in place of `1:probesnum` if there is ever the possibility that probesnum may be equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your code was close.  The issue is in

```
  paste("SNP1":"SNP",probesnum)
         ^^^^^^^^^^
              |--  specifically, this part
```

Compare whats above with @BenBolker's first answer.

The sequence operator, `:`, must be used on numbers (integers or reals)
THEN the sequence can be `paste`'d to a string.

In your code you were giving it two strings and asking it to create a sequence, which `:` does not know how to do.

Comment: No prob.  If @Ben's answer solved your problem (which I assume it did), please make sure to click the check mark next to it indicating as such.